# Where should I store my log file so a user has write permissions to it?

Tags: windows

I currently store my log file in the Program Files\My App folder but some users don't have permission to write here if they are not a power user or administrator. Is there a common location for this type of log file?

#### Update:

I'm currently using Application.StartupPath.

```
logFileLocation = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
```

Answer (score 4):

[I'd use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx) and then [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) that with ApplicationName\Version\LogFileName

Comment: AFAIK, this will work only if the user that creates the file is the only one who needs to write to it. If multiple users need to write the file, then "Common App Data" is the best place, but you must use a service to manage file access.

Comment: From MSDN:  "CommonApplicationData:  The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data that is used by all users."

Answer (score 0):

I would use the temporary folder.

Use the function [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx) on the Windows API,
or [Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) in .NET

Comment: By definition, the temporary folder is where you store temporary, throw-away files that are supposed to be deletable at any time.
Depending on whether the log file is supposed to be kept across sessions or not, it may not be a good choice to put it there...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to a log file, write to the [event log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx). It's managed by a system service, so you don't have to worry about any particular user's storage permissions. If you write to the general application event log, then your application's messages will be mixed with everything else from the system, so when you request the logs from your customer, you'll get to see what else was happening on the system when your application failed. You can also write to an application-specific event log.